# Estimate how many consecutives true elements there is in a vector in R

Tags: r, boolean

I have a really large boolean vector (i.e. `T` or `F`) and I want to simply be able to estimate how many "blocks" of consecutive `T` there are in my vector contained *between* the  `F` elements.

A simple example of a vector with 3 of these consecutive "blocks" of `T` elements:

```
x <- c(T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,F,T,T)
```

Output:

```
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,3,3
```

Comment: (1) Do you mean the final output here should just be 3?  Or are you saying that you want a running tally so that, at any point in your sequence, you can have an estimate of how many `T` blocks have occurred so far?  (2) What constitutes a block - more than 1 `T`?  (3) You said you want to know how many blocks are _between_ `F` elements, but you include the two `T` blocks on either end of the sequence, which are not between `F`.  Which is it?

Comment: You could try using run-length encoding; this collapses your TRUE/FALSE runs : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
rle <- rle(x)
rle$values <- with(rle, cumsum(values) * values)
inverse.rle(rle)

[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 3 3
```

And a simplified and more elegant version of the basic idea (proposed by @Lyngbakr):

```
with(rle(x), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))
```

Comment: Or even `with(rle, rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))`

Comment: @Lyngbakr very nice idea, I added it to my post. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `rle`/`inverse.rle`:

```
x <- c(T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,F,T,T)
rle_x <- rle(x)
rle_x$values[rle_x$values] <- 1:length(which(rle_x$values))
inverse.rle(rle_x)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 3 3
```